# Interfacing ft5x06 touchscreen with yocto

Tags: embedded, interrupt, yocto, device-tree, imx6

I get the following `dmesg` output from my kernel created with yocto.

```
bus: 'i2c': add driver edt_ft5x06
bus: 'i2c': driver_probe_device: matched device 1-0038 with driver edt_ft5x06
bus: 'i2c': really_probe: probing driver edt_ft5x06 with device 1-0038
edt_ft5x06 1-0038: no default pinctrl state
edt_ft5x06 1-0038: probe
edt_ft5x06 1-0038: no platform data?
edt_ft5x06: probe of 1-0038 failed with error -22
i2c-core: driver [edt_ft5x06] registered
```

My device tree contains:

```
smarc_i2c_cam: i2c-gpio-1 {
    compatible = "i2c-gpio";
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_smx6_i2c_gpio_1>;
    gpios =
        <&gpio4 10 0>, /* sda */
        <&gpio1 6 0>;  /* scl */
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    i2c-gpio,delay-us = <2>;
};

polytouch: edt-ft5x06@38 {
    compatible = "edt,edt-ft5x06";
    reg = <0x38>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    //pinctrl-1 = <&edt_ft5x06_pins>;
    interrupt-parent = <&gpio3>;
    interrupts = <1 8>;
};
```

My board is smarc-samx6i (imx6q "Freescale" processor).
Linux kernel is 3.10.17.

But touch is not responding; even the i2c is not responding. Is there anything else I need to take care of?

Comment: You have mistakes in your device tree. But I think you just have them wrong here on the side, otherwise your whole image cant be created.

Comment: Kernel is compiling successfully and i can understand that my device tree is having some configuring in the interrupt pin configuration. Can you have any of document that show how this two syntax define    " interrupt-parent = <&gpio3>;
    interrupts = <1 8>; "

Answer (score 1):

I have a lenmaker 7inch touch screen with the "EDT-FT5x06" touch controller on a Lenmaker BananaPro (A20) running on a mainline linux kernel 4.6.

Here is the patch of my device tree. Look at the `wake-gpios` and the `interrupts`.

```
diff --git a/arch/arm/boot/dts/sun7i-a20-bananapro.dts b/arch/arm/boot/dts/sun7i-a20-bananapro.dts
index 18fcc87..50f1a36 100644
--- a/arch/arm/boot/dts/sun7i-a20-bananapro.dts
+++ b/arch/arm/boot/dts/sun7i-a20-bananapro.dts
@@ -147,6 +147,26 @@
status = "okay";
 };

+&i2c3 {
+   status = "okay";
+   pinctrl-names = "default";
+   pinctrl-0 = <&i2c3_pins_a>;
+   edt: edt-ft5x06@38 {
+           compatible = "edt,edt-ft5x06";
+           reg = <0x38>;
+           interrupt-parent = <&pio>;
+           interrupts = <7 9 IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_FALLING>;
+           wake-gpios = <7 7 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
+           pinctrl-names = "default";
+           pinctrl-0 = <&edt_ft5x06_pins>;
+           touchscreen-size-x = <1024>;
+           touchscreen-size-y = <600>;
+           touchscreen-inverted-x;
+           touchscreen-swapped-x-y;
+   };
+};
+
+
&ir0 {
  pinctrl-names = "default";
  pinctrl-0 = <&ir0_rx_pins_a>;
@@ -222,6 +242,14 @@
allwinner,drive = <SUN4I_PINCTRL_10_MA>;
  allwinner,pull = <SUN4I_PINCTRL_NO_PULL>;
  };
+
+   edt_ft5x06_pins: edt_ft5x06_pins@0 {
+       allwinner,pins = "PH7", "PH9";
+       allwinner,function = "gpio_out";
+       allwinner,drive = <SUN4I_PINCTRL_40_MA>;
+       allwinner,pull = <SUN4I_PINCTRL_NO_PULL>;
+   };
+
};

 &reg_usb1_vbus {
```

Maybe you found more in this documentation from the linux kernel module: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/input/touchscreen/edt-ft5x06.txt

or here: http://linux-sunxi.org/Touchscreen

Comment: I given all the information as per above guidence and i found that i am using a gpio i2c and the same bus is shared by two devices so that i add i2cmux in the device tree again the error while probing the edt-ft5x06 is same as edt_ft5x06 1-0038: no platform data?
edt_ft5x06: probe of 1-0038 failed with error -22
i2c i2c-1: new_device: Instantiated device edt-ft5x06 at 0x38

Answer (score 1):

The edt ft5x06 driver in 3.10.17 kernel is not device tree enabled. You will have to backport the driver from a more recent kernel like 4.1 or later and then you will be able to use device trees with the driver.

Comment: Apart from using from device tree can i manually load the touch screen module to the kernel 3.10.17 and use it?

Comment: I did not really understand your question. If the driver is changed for device tree correctly and the compiled with correct device tree, you can dynamically load the module.

Comment: I added the module using menuconfig add make it.Is that ok to add manually from cd /lib/modules/3.10.17-rel1.0\+g232293e/kernel/drivers/input/touchscreen/ after booting up kernel.

Comment: 3.10.17 kernel used for Yocto is device tree enabled.

Comment: Yes but the edt-ft5x06 driver isn't. See [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/touchscreen/edt-ft5x06.c?v=3.10#L707).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117157/discussion-between-berlin-vince-joe-and-sanchayan).

Comment: **Please help to figure out what is the problem i am already shared my device and OS that i am using now the problem is the dmesg not showing any error regarding the platfom data and when i am _modprobe_ applied for my device i am getting following output in my dmesg as follows  `i2c 2-0039: uevent
i2c 2-0039: uevent
i2c i2c-2: client [edt_ft5x06] registered with bus id 2-0039
i2c i2c-2: new_device: Instantiated device edt_ft5x06 at 0x39
i2c 2-0039: uevent
i2c-core: driver [edt_ft5x06] registered
i2c 2-0039: uevent` any idea what is the problem actually**

Comment: @ Sanchayan: Managed to get the correct driver for the FT5316 and compiled successfully. Now the touchscreen values are coming on /dev/input/touchscreen0 . But we are not able to calibrate the touchscreen. Is there anything I missed out ...